# 'Subquery returns more than 1 row' error for simple case

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I am new to MySQL Functions. I am baffled on 'Subquery returns more than 1 row' error for the below simple case.

This is my function.

```
mysql> create function UserLNFromUsername (username VARCHAR(20)) 
       RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
       return (select last_name from users where username = 'steve' );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

This is the error that I encounter.

```
mysql> select UserLNFromUsername('steve');
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

This is the result of the query which returns only one row.

```
mysql> select last_name from users where username = 'steve';
+-----------+
| last_name |
+-----------+
| Goldstein |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please put a little more effort into asking your question.

Answer (score 2):

your function is using `username` twice;

```
mysql> create function UserLNFromUsername (username VARCHAR(20)) 
       RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
       return (select last_name from users where username = 'steve' );
```

You use `UserLNFromUsername('steve')`, so the where query will become `where 'steve' = 'steve'`, so it will return all records from the table.

I would suggest to rename the parameter, for example:

```
mysql> create function UserLNFromUsername (requestedusername VARCHAR(20)) 
       RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
       return (select last_name from users where username = 'steve' );
```

But you probably want to use this:

```
mysql> create function UserLNFromUsername (requestedusername VARCHAR(20)) 
       RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
       return (select last_name from users where username = requestedusername );
```

Answer (score -1):

Your function is supposed to return a string.  This query:

```
select last_name from users where username = 'steve'
```

is returning more than one record.  Therefore your function doesn't know what to do.  It can't convert multiple records to a single string.

What you do about this depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: although the question was not clear before the edit, it shows that that query returns 1 record